# SQL select row into a string variable without knowing columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, string, dynamic

I am new to writing SQL and would greatly appreciate help on this problem. :)

I am trying to select an entire row into a string, preferably separated by a space or a comma. I would like to accomplish this in a generic way, without having to know specifics about the columns in the tables.

What I would love to do is this:

```
DECLARE @MyStringVar NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
@MyStringVar = SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE ID = @ID AS STRING
```

But what I ended up doing was this:

```
DECLARE @MyStringVar = ''
DECLARE @SecificField1 INT
DECLARE @SpecificField2 NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @SpecificField3 NVARCHAR(1000)
...
SELECT @SpecificField1 = Field1, @SpecificField2 = Field2, @SpecificField3 = Field3 FROM MyTable WHERE ID = @ID
SELECT @StringBuilder = @StringBuilder + CONVERT(nvarchar(10), @Field1) + ' ' +  @Field2 + ' ' + @Field3
```

Yuck. :(

I have seen some people post stuff about the COALESCE function, but again, I haven't seen anyone use it without specific column names.

Also, I was thinking, perhaps there is a way to use the column names dynamically getting them by:

```
SELECT [COLUMN_NAME] FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'MyTable'
```

It really doesn't seem like this should be so complicated. :(

What I did works for now, but thanks ahead of time to anyone who can point me to a better solution. :)

EDIT:
Got it fixed, thanks to everyone who answered. :)

Comment: Could you explain what your end goal is? If we better understand that,  we may be able to suggest a better solution.

Comment: I too am curious as the purpose such a generic routine. I would not use any such solution in production code.

Comment: My overall goal is to track deletion (via trigger) in a database and write changes to a logfile. 
I want the string because I am trying to pass a row as a parameter to a DLL function (written in C#, takes row as string) that writes the deleted data to a logfile. I want a generic approach because I will probably have to write this trigger for every table in the database. The msdn page says DDL triggers don't track row deletion, unfortunately, so it seems I have to write this trigger over and over. If this is the case, I'd at least like to dynamically adjust to any changes made to the tables.

Comment: @Brandi, I'd hand code the triggers for speed (write each trigger with the exact columns and necessary formatting for each column based on need and data type), why add the overhead of looking up the columns each time your trigger fires?  You could easily modify the query in my answer, which uses INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS, to generate the INSERT code for each table.

Comment: First, I'm assuming that you want to track DML as opposed to DDL. The above solution would not work for DDL. SQL Server (2k,2k5,2k8) triggers definitely fire on deletes. In the above solution, if the column order changes, your output will be garbled. Frankly, I think it would be better to write a script to write the triggers (or use a 3rd party program, or 2k8's change tracking) than to use this approach but I do not know all the details of your problem.

Comment: @Thomas: Yes, I am using a DML trigger... I was just saying I wish I could write a database-wide delete trigger instead of having to do it on each table. This was my reason for wanting a more generic approach. Also, I didn't want to have to rewrite triggers if the columns in any of the tables got added/deleted/changed.

As far as the order goes, I modified KM's code to the point where it output 'ColumnName:Value' for each value in that row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

give this a try:

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX), @YourTable nvarchar(200)
SET @YourTable='YourTableName'
SELECT @SQL=
    STUFF(
             (
                  SELECT
                  ' + '','' + COALESCE(''''''''+CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),['+c.COLUMN_NAME+']'+CASE WHEN c.DATA_TYPE='datetime' THEN ',121' ELSE '' END+')+'''''''',''null'')'
                      FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
                      WHERE c.TABLE_NAME = 'ap_voucher'
                      ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION
                      FOR XML PATH('')
             ), 1, 9, ''
         )
SET @SQL = 'SELECT ' + @SQL + ' FROM '+@YourTable
exec (@SQL)
```

sample output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
'030',null,'I','Zzz0',null,'1000021111          ','2000-03-01 00:00:00.000'
'001',null,'I','zzz0',null,'900099618           ','1999-12-03 00:00:00.000'
'001',null,'I','ET10',null,'KOU557              ','1999-11-01 00:00:00.000'
'001',null,'I','Mzzz',null,'017288              ','1999-11-12 00:00:00.000'
```

Comment: Great answer - This is the type of approach I've been looking for. Is it possible to add a condition to control which rows are output? Ideally, I'd like to have this result, but with the added condition 'WHERE ID=@ID'.

Comment: @Brandi, just make the final SET command: `SET @SQL = 'SELECT ' + @SQL + ' FROM '+@YourTable+' WHERE ID='+CONVERT(nvarchar(100),@ID)` and you are all set to go.

Answer (score 1):

To do it dynamically, just knowing the table name, you can use this approach:

```
DECLARE @nSQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @nSQL = COALESCE(
     @nSQL + ' + '','' + CAST(ISNULL([' + c.COLUMN_NAME + '], '''') AS NVARCHAR(MAX))', 
    'CAST([' + c.COLUMN_NAME + '] AS NVARCHAR(MAX))')
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
WHERE c.TABLE_NAME = 'TestTable'

SET @nSQL = 'SELECT ' + @nSQL + ' FROM YourTable'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @nSQL
```

It depends what your end goal is though.

This will handle null values in the columns, but (e.g.) NULL integers come out as 0 for example.

Comment: you should add a CONVERT and a COALESCE for each field in the generated @nSQL, so numeric and null columns don't break the final concatenation: `Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ',' to data type int.`

Comment: @KM - cheers, good catch! I intended to handle ints/nulls etc. but I put the CAST around the COLUMN_NAME instead of inside the string to execute! Corrected the SQL.

Comment: See my answer, I use a different column concatenation technique, which prevents duplicate formatting of the column value.  I also quote values, format datetimes, and show NULLs...

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is you cannot do that.

The only thing you can do is similiar to what you have.

```
SELECT @MyField1 = MyField1, @MyField2= MyField2...etc FROM MyTable
```

And then you can concat these fields:

```
SELECT @MyResult = (SELECT @MyField1 + @MyField2 + MyField3...)

SELECT @MyResult
```

Comment: Why not SELECT MyField1 + MyField2 + MyField3 FROM Table?

Comment: @wwosik I was only using variables because the OP may need those variables later in the procedure, but that too is valid.

Comment: Yea, not knowing what the results columns are in the query sounds a bit like creating a veeery generic access method. Or rather a Debug.Print

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work, if you can handle XML formatted output:

```
DECLARE @MyStringVar NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
SET @MyStringVar = (SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE ID = @ID FOR XML RAW)

SELECT @MyStringVar
```

As an extra bonus, if your data is amenable to it, you can strip away the XML formatting with this, instead of the `SELECT @MyStringVar`:

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@MyStringVar, '<row ', ''), '="', ' '), '" ', ', '), '"/>', '')
```

If your data includes any of the characters that get used in the tags, of course you'll have to do some extra conversion, but this should get you pretty close to what you want.

---

Just noticed that it looks like you don't actually want the column names to display as well as the data.  In that case one of the information_schema queries in the other answers would be the best way to get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is change tracking, then I would recommend against using concatenation as suggested by KM.

1. The order of the columns must remain unchanged. If the column order changes even slightly, the meaning of the values will be vague at best or more likely lost. It is recommended that you never rely on the column order.
2. As a table gets wider and/or contains lots of data, the concatenation will get slower. SQL Server is not know for having efficient concatenation. Further, imagine a table with a couple of dozen nvarchar(max) fields with say 2000 characters each. That will produce a string that is on the order of 48K!
3. You may need to change the delimiter. Suppose I have a value equal "'Pain','Suffering' and 'Trouble'". This type of entry will create problems when you go to analyze the data.

If you are using SQL Server 2008, I would recommend using SQL Server's change tracking mechanism. If you are not using that, then I would recommend purchasing a third-party auditing tool. If that is also not an option, then I would write the deleted value into another table using a trigger. That, at least, forces you to ensure that the auditing data schema is synchronized with the source schema.